# subversion/ tortoisesvn- changing the directory of a repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, hgsubversion

I have a project in a directory projects/projectA. it has a corresponding subversion repository. I'm using Tortoisesvn as the front end.

I'm trying to move the project to projects/projectA_old and cannot find a way to do it. looks like renaming from tortoise works only on directories inside the project and not the project directory itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the directory from the operating system - its name is not significant to SVN.